# Pivoting dataframe to wide from long to remove duplicates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has duplicate person_id values (for every city that they have lived in). I want to pivot the dataframe to a wide format to delete these duplicates.

Original dataframe:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person.Id = c(123L, 345L, 345L, NA), City_lived = c("NY", 
"NY", "Boston"), Current_Patient = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), DOB = c("11/20/97", "10/10/92", "10/10/92")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Desired dataframe:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Person.Id = c(123L, 345L), City_lived_Boston = c(0L, 
1L), City_lived_NY = c(1L, 1L), Current_Patient = c("Yes", 
"Yes"), DOB = c("11/20/97", "10/10/92")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Your input data seeems to be corrupted.  Please check how you got that data.  The structure shows 4 values for Person.Id, where as City_lived and Current_Patient is of length 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  na.omit %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = City_lived, values_from = City_lived, 
   values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, names_prefix = 'City_lived_')
```